# insecure content from file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png

Tags: android

I am getting the error mentioned in subject line while exceuting a webview with shared preferenes. I have posted the code and logcat as well. Please advise as to where i might be going wrong? I am basically trying to open a https site in webview  and retrieving the id/pwd using shared preferences

```
    package com.example.sharedpref;



    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import com.example.sharedpref.R;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


        private Button mSaveButton;
        private Button mSaveButton1;
        private EditText mInputidText;
        private EditText mInputpwdText;
        private WebView mWebView;
        private WebChromeClient mWebchromeclient;
        private WebViewClient mWebViewClient;
        public static final String PREF_STRING = "https://kee.mahindrasatyam.com/_layouts/mobile/mobilesearch.aspx";


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
            mInputidText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            mInputpwdText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            mSaveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            mSaveButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
              mSaveButton.setOnClickListener(this);
              mSaveButton1.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int id = v.getId();
            String message = "";

                if (id == R.id.button1){
                    SharedPreferences sp=getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor Ed=sp.edit();
                Ed.putString("Unm", mInputidText.toString() );              
                Ed.putString("Psw",mInputpwdText.toString());   
                Ed.commit();
                    message="Text Saved in Preferences";

                    }


                else   if (id == R.id.button2){

                    try{
                    SharedPreferences sp1=getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);;



                mWebView = new WebView(this) {

                };
                mWebchromeclient = new WebChromeClient() {

                };

                mWebView.setWebChromeClient(mWebchromeclient);
                mWebView.setWebViewClient(mWebViewClient);
                setContentView(mWebView);

                /* Load the last saved preference. */
                mWebView.loadUrl(sp1.getString(PREF_STRING, "https://kee.mahindrasatyam.com/_layouts/mobile/mobilesearch.aspx"));            }

                catch (Exception e) {
                  Log.i(" connect secon button exception:",""+PREF_STRING);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }

            Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }



      }}



Logcat:
08-17 12:32:03.854: D/TextLayoutCache(16359): Using debug level: 0 - Debug Enabled: 0
08-17 12:32:04.144: D/libEGL(16359): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
08-17 12:32:04.164: D/libEGL(16359): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
08-17 12:32:04.184: D/libEGL(16359): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
08-17 12:32:04.194: D/libEGL(16359): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
08-17 12:32:04.324: D/OpenGLRenderer(16359): Enabling debug mode 0
08-17 12:32:07.124: D/chromium(16359): Unknown chromium error: -400
08-17 12:32:07.204: D/dalvikvm(16359): GC_CONCURRENT freed 249K, 4% free 9001K/9287K, paused 3ms+7ms
08-17 12:32:07.274: W/Web Console(16359): The page at https://kee.mahindrasatyam.com/_layouts/mobile/mobilesearch.aspx displayed insecure content from file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png.
08-17 12:32:07.274: W/Web Console(16359):  at null:1
08-17 12:32:24.564: D/OpenGLRenderer(16359): Flushing caches (mode 1)
08-17 12:32:24.564: D/OpenGLRenderer(16359): Flushing caches (mode 0)
08-17 12:32:24.894: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(16359): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
08-17 12:37:14.944: D/TextLayoutCache(16676): Using debug level: 0 - Debug Enabled: 0
08-17 12:37:15.004: D/libEGL(16676): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
08-17 12:37:15.014: D/libEGL(16676): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
08-17 12:37:15.014: D/libEGL(16676): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
08-17 12:37:15.014: D/libEGL(16676): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
08-17 12:37:15.084: D/OpenGLRenderer(16676): Enabling debug mode 0
08-17 12:37:28.584: D/dalvikvm(16676): GC_CONCURRENT freed 270K, 4% free 9003K/9351K, paused 9ms+8ms
08-17 12:37:33.124: W/Web Console(16676): The page at https://kee.mahindrasatyam.com/_layouts/mobile/mobilesearch.aspx displayed insecure content from file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png.
08-17 12:37:33.124: W/Web Console(16676):  at null:1
08-17 12:38:59.484: D/OpenGLRenderer(16676): Flushing caches (mode 1)
08-17 12:39:00.354: D/OpenGLRenderer(16676): Flushing caches (mode 0)
08-17 12:40:48.764: D/OpenGLRenderer(16676): Flushing caches (mode 1)
08-17 12:40:48.854: D/OpenGLRenderer(16676): Flushing caches (mode 0)
08-17 12:40:49.504: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(16676): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

Answer (score 0):

[Mixed content warning](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=81637). Chromium warns on because the content is not loaded with https like the aspx page. Chromium doesn't like the fact that you are loading mixed-content on a page accessed using https. It's security warning since it could undermine the security of the page. Is your image not displaying or being blocked? See this similar question [SSL: Why does Chrome report mixed content? (Drupal 6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437889/ssl-why-does-chrome-report-mixed-content-drupal-6). The question specfically mentions Chrome which is also based on chromium.