# Webview page loading error

Tags: android, webview, ssl-certificate

Implemented a webview inside a app. It is opening some https pages.It has some ssl issues. I have added those conditions also to ask from user to proceed or not.Now successfully opening pages in higher android version ,giving error in android 4.1.1

Below is the error

```
external/chromium/net/socket/ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc:79‌​2: [0506/103431:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc(792)] handshake failed; returned 0, SSL error code 5, net_error -107
```

The page at https://something.aspx displayed insecure content from

> file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png. at null:1

Comment: can you share your error log? are you using chromium?

Comment: i tested this on emulater. Basic browser is installed .

Comment: external/chromium/net/socket/ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc:792: [0506/103431:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc(792)] handshake failed; returned 0, SSL error code 5, net_error -107

Comment: The page at https://abc.aspx displayed insecure content from file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png.

Comment: Try this in real device

Comment: and post error log in question , edit the question

Comment: Do not have the 4.1.1 device, Only devices running 5.0 are available

Answer (score 1):

[Mixed content warning](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=81637). Chromium warns on because the content is not loaded with https like the aspx page. Chromium doesn't like the fact that you are loading mixed-content on a page accessed using https. It's security warning since it could undermine the security of the page. Is your image not displaying or being blocked? See this similar question [SSL: Why does Chrome report mixed content? (Drupal 6).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437889/ssl-why-does-chrome-report-mixed-content-drupal-6) The question specfically mentions Chrome which is also based on chromium.

Comment: The error you are getting is of the chromium, as chromium doesnt like to be loaded with other than https

Comment: And the main reason is , starting from android 4.4 google has replaced its web protocols to Chromium, and the decvice you are testing with is below 4.4, meaning it will have different protocols then the other devices

Comment: Thats what i said, your TSL version might be higher than 1.0 , TSL version higher than 1.0 are only supported in android 4.4 and above

Comment: What is the solution to open same page in android 4.3 or below ?

Comment: I don't think its possible to open the same page in below android 4.4

Comment: Check this https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=Android&version=4.3

Comment: If my answer helped you , dont forget to accept the answer and rate up :)